# Problem in .fig to .eps conversion (MATLABR 2015b)

Tags: matlab, format, matlab-figure, eps

I am generating a matlab figure with features

1. Separate background regions generated using patch command
2. A couple of arrows using arrow.m (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow)
3. Annotations,Labels,etc

I have tried Matlab option to convert to .eps format as well as print2eps.m from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig. In both cases I get following warning

**Warning: Loading EPS file failed, so unable to perform post-processing. This is usually because the figure contains a large number of patch objects. Consider exporting to a bitmap format in this
case.**

Following is the screenshot of two images. Left is Matlab, Right is in latex

[image]

As one can obverse, output file is not anywhere near to original matlab figure. Any thoughts on addressing this issue would be much appreciated

Comment: Well, it seems like the warning it gives you is pretty relevant. You haven't attached the EPS file, so I can't look at it, but it seems like Matlab is telling you your content is too complicated. for it to convert into an EPS So its not really a surprise that the resulting EPS isn't correct. I'd guess that Matlab gave up when it reached an internal limit, which is why you have a partial result in the EPS.

Comment: I agree what you said about the warning. Does it mean that one cannot get eps file if figure is too heavy. But this sounds very restrictive given how visualization is getting more intense.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know the answer, I'm not a Matlab expert.

Comment: Which “Matlab option” did you try? ‘print’ didn’t work?

Comment: From file drop down menu, I did save as .eps format

Comment: Additional remark: EPS doesn't support transparency. So your magenta and cyan patch will always be displayed opaque.

Comment: from past experience, save to svg and use inkscape to translate to eps

Comment: Your figure does not seem to have so many patch objects ... provide the code to generate the figure so one can try on machine with larger spec e.g. 32GB of ram ...